# NaN in javascript showing up when using a text input field to sum

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, nan

I need to sum a value with another one that comes from input text.

HTML

```
<%= f.text_field :hoursclass, id:"txt_hours" %>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  var price = <%= @room.price %>;
  var qtdhours =  parseInt($(':input[id="txt_hours"]').val());
  var total = qtdhours * <%= @room.price %>

  $("#txt_hours").keyup(function() { 
    $('#reservation_days').text(qtdhours);
    $('#reservation_sum').text(total);
 });
```

`$('#reservation_sum').text(total);` returns NaN

Tks in advance

Comment: Your total is calculated *once*, when the page first loads - what value does the input have at that moment? (Is the input created later, dynamically?) You need to do the calculation from inside the key event handler.

Comment: Tku @nnnnnn ..you help me find my error. I just change the place of the   `$("#txt_hours").keyup(function() { `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for undefined or blank value before doing the calculation, also make sure @room.price has numeric values.

```
$(function() {
  var total=0;
  var price = <%= @room.price %>;
  var qtdhours =  parseInt($(':input[id="txt_hours"]').val());
  if (qtdhours != undefined || qtdhours !='') {
    total = qtdhours * <%= @room.price %>
  }

  $("#txt_hours").keyup(function() { 
    $('#reservation_days').text(qtdhours);
    $('#reservation_sum').text(total);
 });
```